# dummy (interval) for year/distance in regression

Tags: r

I have a dataset for a rent regression in r, have picked my model but I can't create dummies for either building year or distance (from an object in my model).

I have a column for both, one in meters (0;5500) and the other in years (1260;2017).

How to create a dummy or intervals for e.g. buildings in the 0m to 500m range respectively for building year 1260-2012; 2013; 2014-2017?

Comment: Question is very unclear. Please improve your question, add example data (what is rent regression?), define what you mean by "dummy" or "model".

Comment: If you have a column with values from 0 to 5500 and you wish to split this up into intervals, maybe `cut` could help you. See `?cut`. If you want to have a dummy for each year in your regression, look at `factor` and have a look at what happens when you convert year to a factor before you run your regression.